# ApexCharts, duplicated line which is straight

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

I have a bug where the line of chart is duplicated, but it's straight.
The dates are fine, I even did two functions (one php, second js) to parse dates.
Also, the records are not duplicated, once record for a day.

```
`https://codepen.io/WilczekCK/pen/mdLEagrzzz`
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw27n.png)

Comment: If you can create a Codepen or JSFiddle, you will receive help faster.

Comment: Will try to do it, but I have +3000 records and it happens only when a huge amount of records are inserted.

Comment: Codepen: https://codepen.io/WilczekCK/pen/mdLEagr

Comment: Did you check, the JSON data? It isn't sorted. In the beginning itself, it has data for October and then September.

Comment: Also a sidenote, you do not have to remove the reference code in question. I just asked to create codepen so that it will help someone to try out quickly and check what is missing.

Comment: Yup, thats the source of problem.
Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Cool @WilczekCK